# Regular callback scheduling

Tags: windows, kernel

I am looking for a way to schedule a callback function at a regular frequency (say 1hz) within the NT kernel. Is there any framework support for that? I read in one of the posts that a timer object can be used for that, but I did not find any example or any documentation for this use case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`SetTimer` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) in the Windows API. It allows you to pass a callback function pointer.

Note that you must have a working Windows message pump for this function to work - the callback occurs as part of the message processing.  The OS doesn't just interrupt your program and jump to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. I am looking for something in the kernel and not user space. I just came across WdfTimers msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/… I think this might help.

Comment: @user1546438, sorry I misread "within the NT kernel" to mean that the function was part of the kernel, not that it would be *called* from the kernel.